# Unity - How to keep car speed on slants?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a car game, using Kenney's cars and city roads meshes. All is working fine, except for cars on slants. I think this is most a logic question than code...

The behaviour I'm facing is "normal", when you think about physics and gravity: when my car tries to climb up a slant, it slows down, and when my car tries to climb down a slant, it speeds up.

But I want a more cartoon/non-realistic physics, keeping car's speed when it reaches an slant.

Since I'm using WheelCollider to handle car's movement, I thought I need to increase/decrease motor torque on slants, according the direction (up or down), but can't figure out a best way to do that... It's just an ideia, that may be very very very wrong.

So, can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: What happens if you disable gravity on the vehicle? I can try it out later, but curious.

Comment: @ps2goat disabling gravity on the vehicle makes the car go to infinite and beyond hahaha... when try to climb up, the car gets an angle up and can't go down, and when try to climb down, just cant go down

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **WheelCollider**, I am assuming you are using Unity3D's physics system to get your car moving. If you wanted every car to react consistently to slopes without speed up and slowdowns I believe the physics system will prevent your from doing so easily, and you might have a better time coding your own system for car movement.

**However**, if you wanted to continue using the Unity physics system  regardless, I would say gravity  is what is making your movement inconsistent.

A solution would be to separate your vehicles gravity from world space gravity.

While you car close enough to the ground, you could apply a downwards gravity relative to the cars orientation, therefore the car would attach itself to the surface its driving on.

If the car is not touching or is too far away from the ground, you could reapply world space gravity to make sure the car actually falls back down, regardless of its orientation.